# Is there a way to store elements on a page into an array from the Selector function in Testcafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to testcafe, I have heard that there is a way to do this in Selenium, but I have not used that before either. I have tried storing buttons on a webpage into an array, but it seems like the buttons are not accessible when I try to test if the buttons are able to be accessed within the array.

```js
// For the purposes of this example, let's say there are 2 buttons on the page,
// first one has the label "First" and the second has the label "Second".

test('sample', async t => {
    const numElements = Selector('button').filterVisible().count;
    const elements = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
      elements.push(getButtonIndex(i));
    }
    await t.expect(Selector('button').withText('Second')).eql(elements[1]);
});

getButtonIndex(index) {
    return Selector('button').filterVisible().nth(index);
};
```

Is it possible to store HTML elements into an array with Selector? Or is there another way to do this?

I know it is possible to store individual attributes like the aria-label into an array, but if I had the same aria-label for 2 input elements as an example, how would I access the second one? As far as I know, the nth function in testcafe doesn't seem to work for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem is not related to the nth function - it works properly. The fact is that in the context in which tests are executed, `Selector('button').withText('Second')` and `Selector('button').filterVisible().nth(1)` are different objects even if they point to the same HTML element. Try this comparison:

```js
await t.expect(Selector('button').withText('Second').style).eql(elements[1].style);
```

Comment: .style doesn't seem to work, but I guess what I'm looking for is a way to store DOM elements into an array because when I looked into it further, the array that is created by this function is length=0.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors can be stored in an array - there is no problem with that. The problem is that you have an error in the code above:

```js
const numElements = Selector('button').filterVisible().count;
```

Add `await`:

```js
const numElements = await Selector('button').filterVisible().count;
```